# NodeJS - AOP perform a common action for DB exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a nodejs app, which interacts with database (using sequelize).  Now, my requirement is to raise an alert (snmp trap) whenever there is some issue with db connection.

I can achieve this by using .then().catch() as below:

```
db.myModel.find(...)
.then(function() { //do some processing })
.catch (function(e) {
  // TODO: write code to send an alert
  // ...
})
```

The problem with above code is that I have to repeat several times throughout the code, wherever I am doing DB ops.

I was looking for simpler way like AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) for javascript.  In fact I found a couple of libraries ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-aop) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aopromise)), but I didn't find any way to execute an advice, if the flow goes to  catch block.

In case Java, we had a facility to catch exception pointcut.  I am wondering if we have a similar functionality here.

Comment: Maybe you're over-engineering this? More transparent way would be just to write a module that exports a function that every ``.catch`` block calls? Like ``.catch(myDBErrorHandler)``.
If you are using Express, where you can define middleware, you could define a middleware to handle all errors that are instances of Sequelize Error and just have ``.catch(next)``.
I've been a Java developer, I know that over-engineering is easy to follow you for the rest of your life after being there.

Answer (score 0):

In [aopromise](https://github.com/manokovacs/aopromise) one of the latest (unfortunately undocumented) feature is to add error handler component to the advice. [In the tests](https://github.com/manokovacs/aopromise/blob/master/test/aopromise.test.js#L227) there is an example for that, where a third handler is catching every error happens in the pre, fn, or the post phases.

Here is an example to create a logger aspect logging errors and the "rethrowing" the error. You may decide in your own implementation, whether you want handle or forward the error to the caller.

```
module.exports = function LoggerAspect(options) {
    return new AspectFrame(
        function (preOpts) {
            console.log(options || '', preOpts.originalFunction.name, 'was called with', preOpts.args);
        },
        function (postOpts) {
            console.log(options || '', postOpts.originalFunction.name, 'returned with', postOpts.result);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.error(options || '', postOpts.originalFunction.name, 'throw an exception with', err);
        }
    );
}
```